# How to Add Redux function as a Parameter with Props in React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-functional-component

I have a function "insertProfile" in profilesActions and i want to use it in a functional component.

I am importing this function as following:

```
import { insertProfile } from "../../../actions/profilesActions";
```

Follwing is the component in which i wanted to use this function.

```
const ProfilesAdministration = (props,insertProfile) => {

// Code Here

}

export default connect(null, { insertProfile })( ProfilesAdministration );
```

I tried following techniques but none of them is working for me:

```
({props,insertProfile})

(props,{insertProfile})

({props},{insertProfile})

({insertProfile},props)
```

Please Help.. Thanks

Comment: Hey, Can you improve annotation in question i.e use code blocks properly. Because, I hard to get it understandable.

Comment: You can do this: `const ProfilesAdministration = ({insertProfile}) => {

 `

Comment: This is working but i also want to use props in my component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an action so you also need to dispatch it.
You can use this function as a mapDispatchToProps.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
 insertProfile: (payload) => dispatch(insertProfile(payload)) 
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)( ProfilesAdministration );
```

And now, `insertProfile` is available in your component's props.
All you need to call it. It will dispatch action for you.

You can use it like this: `props.insertProfile()`.

You can check more about it here: https://react-redux.js.org/7.1/api/connect#dispatch

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Now this error is showing " 'dispatch' is not defined"

Comment: const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    insertProfile: (profile) => dispatch(insertProfile(profile)),
  };
};

Comment: Above code resolve my issue. But your answer was very helpful. Thank for saving me.